# Python 3: return longest item in lists of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

If i have this data:

```
a = [['a', 'b', 'b', 'v', 'd'], 
     ['d', 'f', 'g'], ['q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y'], 
     ['x', '123', 'v', 'b'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
```

I want to run a function (preferably single line) that will return `123` as is it has the *longest string length* in the list of lists.  How can I do this?

The only thing I saw was finding the longest list in a list of lists, so this is a slightly different problem.

Comment: @DeepSpace: fixed, typo

Comment: It is a VERY similar problem to the longest list problem you mention. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without any imports, and clean:

```
max((word for L in a for word in L), key=len)
```

Answer (score 5):

I think I would use `itertools` to flatten the nested lists and then use the built-in `max`:

```
from itertools import chain

data = [['a', 'b', 'b', 'v', 'd'],
        ['d', 'f', 'g'], ['q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y'],
        ['x', '123', 'v', 'b'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]

print(max(chain.from_iterable(data), key=len))
# '123'
```

A more naive way would be to find the longest string in every list, then finding the longest string between these:

```
print(max((max(li, key=len) for li in data), key=len))
# '123'
```

Comment: Why make a list of the max element and then index 0?

Comment: @Moberg Indeed, it was a left over of a previous idea I had.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few approaches you could take (this first one is very similar to @DeepSpace's approach).

```
a = [['a', 'b', 'b', 'v', 'd'], 
     ['d', 'f', 'g'], ['q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y'], 
     ['x', '123', 'v', 'b'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]

# flatten the list
flattened = [x for y in a for x in y]
longest_elem = max(flattened, key = lambda x: len(x))
```

You could also use `numpy.argmax` on the lengths of each string:

```
# find the longest element using numpy.argmax
import numpy as np

# store the lengths of each element in `flattened`
lengths = [len(x) for x in flattened]

# find the index of the largest element in `lengths`
longest_elem_index = np.argmax(lengths)

# index `flattened` with the longest element's index from `lengths`
longest_elem = flattened[longest_elem_index]
```